# Strange unnamed property in JSON error object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql

I'm using [pg-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise) in node.js console script.

Node version: v0.10.38
pg-promise version: 1.1.4

I got a connection error due to trivial misconfiguration problem which doesn't care. But I want that my script alert me with a rich explanation of the problem.

If I take the error object passed to the error handler callback and send it "as is" to console via console.log(), then I ca see the text "no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1" in the manner you can see in labelled as "Output 1".

But if this doesn't seem to be a valid JSON object and I don't know how to access the property that has that message.

Also, if I log the result of JSON.stringifgy() over that object, that information simply disappears.

Is this an error of pg-promise implementation? Or it is some kind of JSON hidden attributes and can be accessed in any way?.

Below is a reproduction of the issue:

**Source code:**

```
var pgpLib = require('pg-promise');
var pgp = pgpLib({});
var db = pgp({
        host: "localhost",
        database: "__db_name__",
        user: "__db_user__",
        password: "__db_password__",
});

db.query("select 'foo'").then(
        function(){
                console.log ("Works!!");
        },
        function(err){
                console.log("ERROR!!", err); // (Output 1)
                // console.log("ERROR!!", JSON.stringify(err)); // (Output 2)
        }

);
```

**Output 1:**

```
ERROR!! { [error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "reports", database "ruminant", SSL off]
  name: 'error',
  length: 143,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '493',
  routine: 'ClientAuthentication' }
```

**Output 2:**

```
ERROR!! {"name":"error","length":143,"severity":"FATAL","code":"28000","file":"auth.c","line":"493","routine":"ClientAuthentication"}
```

**EDIT**:

As Trott said (thanks), I can obtain that string by using .toString() method (or forcing string coercion).

But, anyway, the below output doesn't seem valid JSON to me.

I figured out I could achieve the same effect by overloading .toString() method in object's prototype, but I can't:

```
var foo = function(){};

Object.defineProperty(foo.prototype, "toString", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function() {
        return "Some hidden data";
    }
});

var bar = new foo();
console.log("1:", bar, bar.toString());
bar.otherStuff = "foobar";
console.log("2:", bar, bar.toString());
```

Outputs:

```
1: {} Some hidden data
2: { otherStuff: 'foobar' } Some hidden data
```

Comment: What's not valid about it?

Comment: By the way, [pg-promise v.1.3.0](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.1.3.0) improved on handling errors related to the connection.

Comment: Good to know. But, anyway, this question is about data structure that causes shown console.log() output which I didn't achieved to reproduce that yet. If you try to parse it as json it will throw an error. Or simply JSON.parse("{[]}") too.

Answer (score 2):

To just get the error message from an `Error` object without all the other stuff, use `.toString()`.

```
console.log('ERROR! ', err.toString());
```

If you use string concatenation, it should have the same effect:

```
console.log('ERROR! ' + err);
```

The latter way seems to be how [pg-promise README example code](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#error) handles errors.

I've tested both of these with `pg-promise` and they work, but they print "Error: " as part of their message, so you don't really need to include 'ERROR! ' like I did.

Comment: Thanks.

I should thought that.

But my question is pure javascript understanding issue.

I didn't understand from where were comming that data because it isn't present in the actual json object.

Of course: one can overload .toString() method. I checked that too, but I missed the fact that it can be overloaded in object prototype (which is the case).